# Display alt attributes of thumbnail images on product detail page

Tags: product-images, seo, product-view

On the product detail page of the template I'm using I've noticed the thumbnail images don't include an alt attribute. The code is implemented as `alt=""`.

Looking at the product image proper (the one marked default in the admin for the product) I can see the alt attribute is determined by `alt="'.$this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel()).'"`

What's interesting is it seems this is pulled off the product (from *app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Abstract.php*)

```
public function getImageLabel($product = null, $mediaAttributeCode = 'image')
{
    if (is_null($product)) {
        $product = $this->getProduct();
    }

    $label = $product->getData($mediaAttributeCode . '_label');
    if (empty($label)) {
        $label = $product->getName();
    }

    return $label;
}
```

I know the label for each image is in the system, because if I change the default image of the product, the alt attribute of the main product image is now reflective of the newly assigned image. I just need to understand how to fetch the attribute off the image object rather than the product object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be trivial when I looked into it. The `$_image` variable is an instance of `VarienObject` with a `label` property, so it's just a matter of calling `$_image->getLabel()`.

Here's an abridged section of the final code

```
foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image): ?>
    <a href="#" ....>
        <img alt="<?=$_image->getLabel()?> ...
```